# How to build an URL address from a delimited line in a file with bash parameter expension?

Tags: bash, url, wget

How to loop a wget command in bash shell with URL parameters from a file.

File is space delimited :

```
$ cat parameters.txt
ANLA 830093 37227 2018/12/23 C14111
ANLA 2647724 106308 2018/12/23 C301205
BEDER 2638573 94596 2018/12/12 INDISP
.....
```

URL resquests use get method so I would like to to set parameters from a line and build URLs with them.

```
$ for i in (cat parameters.txt);  .. ? setting $p1,$p2,$p3,$p4 ? .. ;wget -qO- "http://example.com/planning.dll?Id=$p1&Prest=$p2&Time=$p3&Date=$p4" | ..processings ... >>output.txt; done
```

Parameter expansions ${....} should be the clue but how ? Or other answer ?

I'd like a way like *cut -d " " -f "colomn"* file command for variables.

Comment: @Cyrus you should update your copypasta to account for the new page

Comment: @vintnes : please post the link here. I don't know about it either ; -)

Comment: MCVE would be nice, but at least edit your Q to show the transformation required from your sample input (line for line). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you know [how to loop over lines of a file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash) and [Why don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Use `while read ...`.

---

Besides that, I would use `read -a` to parse the parameters into an *array*:

```
while read -r -a p ; do
    echo wget  -qO- "http://example.com/planning.dll?Id=${p[1]}&Prest=${p[2]}&Time=${p[3]}&Date=${p[4]}"
done < parameters.txt
```

(Remove the `echo` in front of `wget` when you are ok with it)